# StackoverflowError in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

My application consists of multiple layouts. I've tried reducing the layouts to minimum. It seems to work on all versions of android except on android 4.0.4 where it crashes.

Can anyone help fix this issue? Is this a memory related issue?

The stack trace is given as

```
STACK_TRACE=java.lang.StackOverflowError
at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.drawTextRun(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:295)
at android.text.TextLine.drawTextRun(TextLine.java:1067)
at android.text.TextLine.handleText(TextLine.java:791)
at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:1034)
at android.text.TextLine.drawRun(TextLine.java:397)
at android.text.TextLine.draw(TextLine.java:195)
at android.text.Layout.draw(Layout.java:425)
at android.text.BoringLayout.draw(BoringLayout.java:400)
at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:5265)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11177)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10616)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11180)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10616)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11180)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10616)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11180)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10616)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11180)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10616)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11180)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10616)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10614)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11180)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1788)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10616)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10614)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10614)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10614)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10614)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11180)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1788)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10616)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10614)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11180)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:1923)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10616)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11180)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10616)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10614)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10614)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11180)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10616)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11180)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10616)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10614)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11180)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2295)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10616)
at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:890)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2113)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1837)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2649)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:978)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Looks like overly deep view hierarchy. Try to flatten it more.

Comment: For us to help we need to see your layout code, be it xml or java

Comment: from @dan8912 There are elements in toolbar that can be used depending the android version you are using. Also you have the version in android Manifest file. Try to start checking this..

Comment: Have tried to remove many views possible. But the issue still persists. Will adding android:largeHeap="true" to the manifest file help?

Comment: If you found the issue, can you please share it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are elements in toolbar that can be used depending the android version you are using. Also you have the version in android Manifest file. Try to start checking this..

Comment: This should be a comment, but as you don't have enough rep I've moved it to be one on the post, and I've flagged this for deletion as it's not an answer

Comment: Could you be more specific with this comment. I'm unable to understand how a toolbar can fix or identify this issue.

Comment: There are some android elements that can be user only starting with version 2, 3, 4. If you use an element that comes with android 4 and the device has android 2 the application will crash..